# Calculating capacitor discharge time constant with dc source and constant current source

Tags: batteries, capacitor, power-electronics, discharge

I have a 1.8V dc source with 40 ohms series resistance, which models a battery. In parallel, there is a 10uF capacitor. At t<0, the mosfet is off and there is no load delivered to the output, so the voltage across the 10uF capacitor is 1.8V. At t=0, the mosfet is switched on, and is designed to deliver a constant current source of 5mA (up until it leaves saturation due to a small Vds). The constant current source charges another 1uF output capacitor. At t=inf, the voltage across the 10uF capacitor is 1.8V - 40*5mA = 1.6V, and also the output capacitor.

[image: Quick drawing of the circuit (Updated)]

I would like to know how to calculate the time constant of the voltage discharge curve across the 10uF capacitor, when there is two sources acting on the capacitor.

For the maths, I would like to assume the mosfet stays in saturation well beyond the time constant of the first cap. (Maybe the 10uF cap value needs to be lowered to make this true).

As I understand, The current source mosfet has a changing impedance based on its changing Vds. This changes the R_eq seen by the first capacitor. This is where I get stuck with the maths of calculating the time constant of the first capacitor.

Comment: Hmm, it will be T = 5*RC = 5*40Ω*10µF = 2ms

Comment: What makes you think it's not RC?

Comment: Lump the 5mA source in with the V and its R -- i.e., convert all 3 to a Thevenin equivalent.  Then T = R_eq * C where R_eq is the resistance of the Thevenin equivalent.  (The thevenin voltage is irrelevant.)

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers have made me understand I have over-simplified my question. The current source is actually a mosfet and its output impedance changes. Please see my updated question